# Write registry using nsis

Tags: windows, windows-installer, registry, nsis

I want to run a `.reg` file inside an NSIS installer. My registry file is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}\InprocServer32]
@="SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
```

I tried to run:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}" "SampleV2CredentialProvider"

WriteRegStr HKCR "CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}" "SampleV2CredentialProvider"
```

These are not working for me, and also, I don't know what I should say about the last registry. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using [SetRegView](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/SetRegView). As I was working on a 64-bit operating system, it was trying to look to the registries as a 32bit register by default. Because of that, nothing was happening to my registry file. Setting `SetRegView` to `64` solved the problem for me.

```
SetRegView 64
WriteRegStr "HKLM" "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}" "" "SampleV2CredentialProvider"
WriteRegStr "HKCR" "CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}" "" "SampleV2CredentialProvider"
WriteRegStr "HKCR" "CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}\InprocServer32" "" "SampleV2CredentialProvider.dll"
WriteRegStr "HKCR" "CLSID\{adeba497-0484-4d69-aff3-d7c759f21d15}\InprocServer32" "ThreadingModel" "Apartment"
```